# Tomcat server doesn't reflect in my IDE

Tags: eclipse, tomcat6

I downloaded and installed tomcat 6.0. I am using rational application developer. I am not able to see my tomcat server in my IDE at all. I tried server->new-> and windows->preferences->server->server runtime environment but I don't find it here either. Any idea where I am going wrong or which step i missed? I know i installed my tomcat properly because http:localhost:8080 works properly.
thanks in advance!!

**UPDATE**
Will a trial license affect my servers in any way? Like only a specific server you can use with the IDE while u have a trial license or something like that?

**UPDATE**

when I click Add, Tomcat isn't there in the list of options for me to select and that is where my problem arises. I tried clicking on search and the selecting the tomcat folder but i get an error that states - No new server runtime found

Comment: Is Tomcat 6 a supported server type?

Comment: yes, i know this for a fact because i have a colleague who uses it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and I followed these steps to solve it in Eclipse Helios:

1. Help -> Install New Software
2. Choose "Helios - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios" site
3. Expand "Web, XML, and Java EE Development"
4. Check JST Server Adapters (version 3.2.2)

Please change the download URL in step 2 according to the Eclipse version which you are using.
Hope this helps.